# I cannot change the height and width of an element

Tags: html, css

For some reason the button in the header changes size but the two in the main does not. Why does this happen and how can i fix it? When i inspect my site in the developer tools it shows that the width and height are being applied to the buttons but there is no visual change.

See code here:
https://codepen.io/Burning_Pancakes/pen/JjdNwWg

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Dribbble Double</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <header>
            <img id="logo" src="images/ball.svg" alt="ball"/>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Explore</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hire</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <a class="signup link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </header>

        <main>
            <h1>Dribble Double</h1>
            <p>Find &amp; showcase creative work from the worlds best design professionals</p>
            <a class="signup link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
            <a class="link" id="learn" href="#">Learn More</a>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 12em;
}
#logo {
    height: 50%;
}
nav {
    margin-left: 3em;
    width: 50%;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;

}
li {
        width: 25%;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
.link {
    height: 48px;
    width: 140px;
}
.signup {
    color: #fff;
    background: #01D70B;
}
main {
    height: calc(100% - 100px);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Because ``<a>`` tags have ``display: inline`` by default. Set ``display: inline-block`` to them.

Answer (score 0):

Anchors with link class should have a display:inline-block; property in order to be affected by the sizes attributes (width/height).

change your .link styling

```
.link {
  height: 48px;
  width: 140px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```